# How can I declare a variable using C# in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, variables

I'm trying to declare a string variable right after the body tag from the approach below and display the value for the name variable inside a div tag. But why can't we access the variables outside the declared scripting tag`<%CODE%>`?

In other words, if I declare a variable name somewhere in the HTML code 
as `<% string name="Stark"; %>` and try to access it somewhere down in the code using the code below `<div><%=name;%></div>`...

Then it prompts me with

> The `<VARIABLE NAME>` doesn't exist in current context

Comment: _How_ doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 2):

**ASP.NET MVC**

```c#
@{  
    string name = "Stark";
}

<div>
   <h2>@name</h2>
</div>
```

**ASP.NET WebForms**

```c#
<% string name = "Stark"; %>
<div>
    <h2><%=name %></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: could you do something like <% int i = 0; %> and use it later in a String.Format --> <%# String.Format("{0, 0:C2}", i += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "price"))) %>

Comment: Just try it and you can answer your own question.

Comment: I did try, you think I'd be asking it if I knew how to Implement it ? I'm asking u if there is a way to do it, not necessarely the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= %>` syntax prints an expression.

It doesn't take a full statement (`name;` makes no sense as a statement, and it doesn't make sense to print a statement).

Therefore, it must not have a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old of a topic but I want to answer it for anyone that stumbles upon this question:

For Webforms, ASP.NET separates variable contexts by the tags they are located in. Sometimes you need to set the variable within the same tag as the call (`<%= %>`) you are working with so that ASP.NET will compile it.

So...

```
<label> <!-- scope -->
    <% %>
    <%= %>
<\label>
```

Instead of...

```
<% %>
<label> <!-- scope -->
    <%= %>
<\label>
```

The differences comes when you use an `if`/`for`/`foreach` code blocks in Webforms. The scope surrounding the HTML and C# allows for C# to become the focus instead of the HTML.

This is most likely a scoping issue based on how ASP.NET webforms handles variables in HTML.

If someone can confirm if the scoping ability has improved for razor, that would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It seemed like the question had an incomplete answer. None of the answers mentioned scoping withing the aspx file and just says it should work.